Connection aborted, Remote disconnected (Remote end closed connection without response) in python Session.request()
I am having a trouble with using the request() method of Session class in Python.
In my backend, if I call an API with request()

Method first time there is the response. But if I call this method after 5 minutes, it throws:
Connection aborted, Remote disconnected (Remote end closed connection without response)

But if I call the same API with Postman, it always returns response.
Here is my code snippet.
from requests.sessions import Session as _Session
class Session(_Session):
    def __request(method, url, json, data, files, params):
        try:
            response = self.request(headers, method, url, json, data, files, params)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

I have checked the headers and it was the same in any cases.
What might be the issue?
I have added timeouts=10 but it was not working.

headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'} try with this, might be it will help you

The subclassing of _Session seems incomplete. __request is an instance method and references self, but self isn't defined as a parameter. Where is self declared? Can you share enough code to reproduce your error?

I tried with keep-alive but it was not working.

Hi @OluwafemiSule, it's hard to reproduce on your side. I only get this error on the staging server and it happens sometimes, not always.
